# Help with Django RemoteUserMiddleware RemoteUserBackend with fresh database

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

The 1.3 release of Django includes the `RemoteUserMiddleware` and
`RemoteUserBackend` classes to allow Apache to do authentication.
See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/auth-remote-user/

I have an initial_data.json that creates a superuser when syncdb is performed.  A dumpdata confirms it.

But I find that it doesn't seem to login properly with the newly created database.  I get an ImproperlyConfigured exception that says:
  The Django remote user auth middleware requires the authentication middleware to be installed.

```
Edit your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting to insert django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware' before the RemoteUserMiddleware class.
```

The traceback points to `RemoteMilddleware.process_request()`:

```
def process_request(self, request):
    # AuthenticationMiddleware is required so that request.user exists.
    if not hasattr(request, 'user'):
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(...
```

The DEBUG output from Apache shows that settings in fact have `AuthenticationMiddleware` and `RemoteUserMiddleware` in the requested order:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES  
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')
```

But the request.user attribute is not set, generating the exception.

If I look closer at the source code for django.contrib.auth.backends and middleware, 
I find that `AuthenticationMiddleware` is registering `LazyUser` for
the request class.  But `RemoteUserBackend` doesn't seem to have
the authenticate() method called which is where remote_user gets looked up in the Users table.

Is there something I should be doing to get `authenticate()` to be called in order to create request.user?

I can provide more info as needed.  This is using SSL, by the way.  Does that have some interaction that I didn't anticipate?

I should mention that I'm using Apache2.2.14 and `mod_wsgi`.

Comment: Is this django snippet appropriate?  http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1547/

Comment: I had the same problem when using remote mysql server, but with local one it worked fine

Comment: This was with a local sqlite3 database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and after a little debugging figured out I forgot to create the mysql (I think it's the same case with sqllite) tables for the auth and other apps. So if you didn't you'll need to run python manage.py syncdb or create them some other way

Answer (score 0):

This is an ugly workaround.

I created a unit test case and it worked fine in the stock development environment.  Based on that, I went in to the `RemoteMilddleware.process_request()` function mentioned above on the Apache server and disabled the test for the `user` attribute.  It then worked fine...

I'm not going to select this as the answer, but I thought I should document this workaround for anyone else who gets blocked.  I'll look into filing a bug report.

Anyone know a proper solution or how to attack this in Apache2?  All the traceback and variable information suggests that Apache is setting up the REMOTE_USER correctly but that Django1.3 isn't properly using it to authenticate.